# Java pdfbox Error: could not find or load main class

Tags: java, program-entry-point, pdfbox

I and trying to read some text from a PDF file with PDFbox, i have set the classpath to the jar and everything complies with out errors. (I am doing this from cmd on windows 7) then I run "java test" and I get the following error `Error: could not find or load main class`. I have even tried different example version of code for PDFbox same problem... Here is my code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;
class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PDFParser parser = null;
        PDDocument pdDoc = null;
        COSDocument cosDoc = null;
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper;

        String parsedText;
        String fileName = "test.pdf";
        File file = new File(fileName);
         try {
              parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
              parser.parse();
              cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
              pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
              pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
              parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
              System.out.println(parsedText.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9. ]+", ""));
         } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              try {
                    if (cosDoc != null)
                         cosDoc.close();
                    if (pdDoc != null)
                         pdDoc.close();
              } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
              }

         }
    }
}
```

I know this going to be something so simple that I will slap myself for not seeing it but I have now been looking at this for to long and can't see the wood for the trees. What am I over looking?

Edit: I have tried `public class test {` same problem.

Edit2: Solved knew it be a face slapping moment... i set the class-path wrong `set CLASSPATH=.;C:\project\pdfbox.jar`

Comment: *i have set the classpath to the jar* - have you added both the (jar or path with the) test class and the PDFBox jars (PDFBox has some dependencies...)?

Comment: @mkl this is what I did `set CLASSPATH=C:\Users\me\Desktop\project\pdfbox.jar`

Comment: Your test class is not in pdfbox.jar, is it? You might want to add ".". Furthermore, PDFBox depends on some other libraries but I think there is a jar combining all of that, some pdfbox-all.jar. You might want to use that instead.

Comment: No it is not in the the jar, 
I think I am using that jar, this is the one I am using `pdfbox-app-1.8.10.jar 10.6MB, pre-built PDFBox standalone binary`

Comment: *No it is not in the the jar,* - Then include it in the class path! E.g. if your Test.class is in the current folder, use `set CLASSPATH=.;C:\Users\me\Desktop\project\pdfbox-app-1.8.10.jar`

Comment: Thank, ... as i said knew it be something stupid...

Comment: Ok, I'll make that an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
public class test {
```

Class must be public in order to run it.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's main class is not in the PDFBox jar. Thus, its (base) path must be included in the class path. So instead of

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\PDFBOXLIBFOLDER\pdfbox.jar
```

he needs to do e.g.

```
set CLASSPATH=.;C:\PDFBOXLIBFOLDER\pdfbox.jar
```

(if his test class is in the current directory).